# Neovim - 'plugged' directory cannot be found

Tags: vim-plugin, neovim

I've been trying to set up a neovim environment on my macOS device for react development and when I was trying to install autocompletion plugin (coc-nvim) via vim-plug and when I tried to navigate to the 'plugged' directory it gave me the following error:

`cd: no such file or directory: plugged`

Here is my init.vim file:

```
 syntax on

 :set number
 :set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4
 :set shiftwidth=4
 :set expandtab
 :set smartindent
 :set nu
 :set nowrap
 :set smartcase
 :set noswapfile
 :set incsearch

 :set colorcolumn=80
 
 call plug#begin()

 Plug 'https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline'
 Plug 'https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
 Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/tagbar'
 Plug 'https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim'
 
 call plug#end()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

By default on the MacOS the path is:

```
/Users/{your-user-name}/.local/share/nvim/plugged/
```

Answer (score 1):

https://vi.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this type of question as it relates to (neo)vim and not programming.

That said, if you're looking for the folder in the correct place and vim-plugged didn't create it automatically, just create it yourself. On Linux, the default location is equivalent to:

```
call plug#begin(stdpath('data') . '/plugged')
```

ps. neovim has LSP support builtin starting with version 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

```
call plug#begin('add here path where you want your folder to be , in your case i guess ~/.config/nvim/plugged ')
```

then :InstallPlug